# attachEventOnce() leads to "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, url-routing, sapui5

Following the [best practice guide](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/08887a263aa94c14838593aecddf1529.html) I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

Via a lot of console.logs I've found out that this error is thrown (anonymous in console) in the following code line:

```
oView.getElementBinding().attachEventOnce(....)
```

AttachEventOnce() is the function which causes the problems. Do you have an idea how to solve this or debug further?

The codeblock:

```
        oView.getElementBinding().attachEventOnce("dataReceived", jQuery.proxy(function () {

            var oData = oView.getModel().getData(sReportPath);
            if (!oData) {
                sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this).myNavToWithoutHash({
                    currentView : oView,
                    targetViewName : "namespace.view.NotFound",
                    targetViewType : "XML"
                });
            }
        }, this));
```

Quoted from the best practice guide:

> ```
>           // Check that the product specified actually was found
>           oView.getElementBinding().attachEventOnce("dataReceived", jQuery.proxy(function() {
>               var oData = oView.getModel().getData(sProductPath);
>               if (!oData) {
>                   sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this).myNavToWithoutHash({
>                       currentView : oView,
>                       targetViewName : "sap.ui.demo.tdg.view.NotFound",
>                       targetViewType : "XML"
>                   });
>               }
>           }, this));
> ```

This whole thing is fired in the "routeMatched" section.

Comment: What happens before? There are some line before this call in the best practice guide. Did you try Chrome's functionality to stop at exceptions?

Comment: @matbtt I think I've found the error. It was a problem in the OData backend. I didn't implement "readEntity" ... ah, nevermind, check my answer ;P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the binding context referred to a specific entity it "deferred" (~ looped) endlessly.

However, in the first place the binding uses the following approach:

- Bind everything to the control
- Use the very first item (whatever it is) in the bonded list

But as soon as one hits a different control and thus fires the mentioned codelines, the binding wants to change to a specific entity (http://odataservice/entity('WithASpecificKey')).

The thing is, that if you haven't implemented a "[readEntity](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/tutorials/basicread.html)" method in your OData service, you'll have this error. It seems to be pretty strange at first sight because it works on the initial approach but not after the click. That's why it was/is kind of wired to debug.

What I've done is implementing the "readEntity" method in the OData service correctly.

Answer (score -2):

`attachEventOnce()` doesn't seem to be a standard part of JavaScript (you can verify this by opening your JS console and slecting some arbitrary element on the page, and running `object.attachEventOnce() === undefined;`.) I'm betting that this standard guide defined it earlier in the text. It also appears that `one()` might be the function you want.

Comment: The function attachEventOnce is defined in the SAPUI5/OpenUI5 EventProvider object. As the binding extends this object the function shall be available.